# sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces opening a blank file

Tags: centos, selinux

I'm trying to open a file in a CENTOS VM using `sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces` but all I get is a blank file. What am I missing?

I'm running libselinux-2.5-15.el7.x86_64.

I tried other files as well but no dice, still a blank file.

Comment: This file is not used in CentOS (but would be in Debian for example) so probably doesn't exist. Maybe you could explain *why* you're attempting this.

Answer (score 2):

The config file `/etc/network/interfaces` is for Debian and the distros that are forked from it or in its family such as Ubuntu or Mint.

If you are using CentOS 6 or 7 (preferable 7 because 6 is EOL 12/1/2020), the config file will be either

```
/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-DEVNAME#
```

or

```
/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-DEVNAME#
```

where `DEVNAME#` is the device number and a number that's usually 0, 1, or 2.

If you are using CentOS 8, Network Manager will be used to configure the the interfaces while one of the above files will be used if you install the `network-scripts` package, configure them, and disable and stop the `NetworkManager` service and enable and start the `network` service.

Comment: You probably could just say `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-$DEVICE` where $DEVICE is the network interface to configure.  eth# and enp3s# are not the only possible device names.  See this for more details: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/networking_guide/ch-consistent_network_device_naming

Comment: @jsbillings Done. It depends on the udev rules. I just put those two up there as an example as they what I've usually seen.

Comment: Also, NetworkManager on CentOS7 and 8 use the ifcfg-* files too, so you don't need to remove it to continue to use those configuration files.

Comment: @jsbillings NetworkManager in CentOS 8 is running by default before those files are even on the system. It will continue to run if the files are removed afterwards and doesn't even notice any changes in those files until it's prompted to do so. I only suggest stopping and disabling the service because you don't need to have two services managing the same things.